# Whats the rate limit of google

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-search-api

When I run the code after a while it gives me the code: 429 which means that too many requests have been given to that URL, so after a while, I tried again with the difference that I added up to 10 seconds of delay and still gave me the code. (429)

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import time

query = "programming"

while True:
    response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query)
    print (response.status_code)
    time.sleep(10) # How much delay should I add?
```

output:

```
.
.
.
200
200
200
429
429
429
429
429
429
.
.
.
```

My question is that How much delay should I add to keep the code running all day (like 12 hours) with the response code 200?

Am I doing the ideal way? because I found something on the web about [Quota and pricing for google](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quota-pricing) and wanted to know does that relates to this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using google end-user frontend (what humans see and use to search things on google). There is no documentation regarding its rate limits as I don't think they want you to use it programmatically.

In order to get search results programmatically I think you are suppoosed to use the [Google Custom Search JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) which provides 100 calls per day for free.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. 30-40 seconds between searches.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
#other imports (google API)

sleep(randint(30,40))
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to avoid this is USE a **VPN** or a **Proxy** to overcome rate limit by google. i would recommend switch IP after 100 requests
there are many free VPNs and Free Proxy Sites

Free proxy are a big headache to find one that works.you can refer to this projects

https://github.com/ShiftyTR/Proxy-List

https://github.com/monosans/proxy-list